# How to assign Unique Images to each card in my Deck of Cards in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Programmers
Please, I need your help here.
I am working on a Whot! card game.
I created Classes for Card, Deck, Suit, Rank etc
Below is a sample of My Card Class

```
  package com.giftedegware.wrex;

  import android.media.Image;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

  public class Card {
   private Suit suit;
   private Rank rank;
   public boolean isFaceUp;
   public Image front;
   private Image back;

   /**
    *
    * @param rank
    * @param suit
    */
   public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
    isFaceUp = true;
    this.front = front;
    this.back = back;
   }



   //public methods
   public String getSuit() {
    return suit.printSuit();
   }

   public String printRank() {
    //get Rank as a string
    return rank.printRank();
   }

   //flipCard
   public void flipCard() {

    isFaceUp = !isFaceUp;
   }

   //Get Rank
   public int getRank() {

    return rank.getRank();
   }

   public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    if (isFaceUp) {
     str += rank.printRank() + "of" + suit.printSuit();
    } else {
     str = "Face Down (nothing to see here)";
    }
    return str;
   }
  }
```

The code i used in my Deck.java(Deck Class)for Generating all the Cards in a Deck is:

```
for (Suit suit: Suit.values()){
        for (Rank rank: Rank.values()){
            Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
            card.flipCard();
            this.add(card);
        }
}
```

I have all my card images in my Drawable Folder.
How do I assign each image to their respective Cards?

Please, i appreciate your help in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you must define resource id field for drawable in the card class

current :

```
   private Suit suit;
   private Rank rank;
   public boolean isFaceUp;
   public Image front;
   private Image back;
```

change to:

```
   private Suit suit;
   private Rank rank;
   public boolean isFaceUp;
   public int front;//todo pass resource id drawable
   private int back;//todo  resource id drawable
```

use:

```
card.front=R.drawable.image_name;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. i made the change, but my deck population code isn't working anymore. what should i add to it?:  for (Suit suit: Suit.values()){
            for (Rank rank: Rank.values()){
                Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
                card.flipCard();
                this.add(card);
            }

Comment: How do I implement //card.front=R.drawable.image_name// inside my for loop to generate all the cards and images? or should i create an array of images? how do i link them up to the cards?

Comment: yes. you should create an array of images and Link them with the position number...

Comment: Thanks alot. i made the change, but my deck population code isn't working anymore. what should i add to it?: for (Suit suit: Suit.values()){ for (Rank rank: Rank.values()){ Card card = new Card(rank, suit); card.flipCard(); this.add(card); }....Please,...you can even show me a sample code please.